Why are David's men called "The Thirty" in 2 Samuel 23:24 when verse 39 says there were 37 in total?
Why are David's men called "The Thirty" in 2 Samuel 23:24 when verse 23:39 says there were 37 in total?

The apparent discrepancy is well known and the explanation is widely available.

Thirty and seven in all - This reckoning is correct, though only 36 "names" are given, the names of only two of the second triad being recorded, but 31 names are given from 2 Samuel 23:24 to the end, which, added to the two triads, or six, makes 37. Joab as captain of the whole host stands quite alone. In 1 Chronicles 11:41-47; after Uriah the Hittite, there follow sixteen other names, probably the names of those who took the places of those in the former list, who died from time to time, or who were added when the number was less rigidly restricted to thirty.

Barnes' Notes on the Bible

Uriah] See on ch. 2 Samuel 11:3.thirty and seven in all] This total is obtained either (a) by reckoning three in the first class (2 Samuel 23:8-12), two in the second (2 Samuel 23:18-23), and thirty-two in the third (2 Samuel 23:24-39), emending 2 Samuel 23:34 by the help of Chron. so as to contain three names: or (b) if the text of 2 Samuel 23:34 is retained, by counting three in the second class, though only two are mentioned by name. Joab, as commander-in-chief, is not reckoned in the total.
In 1 Chronicles 11:41-47 sixteen additional names are given, possibly either of those who became members of the body when its number was not rigidly limited to thirty, or of those who took the places vacated by death.

Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges

19-39. the first three—The mighty men or champions in David's military staff were divided into three classes—the highest, Jashobeam, Eleazar, and Shammah; the second class, Abishai, Benaiah, and Asahel; and the third class, the thirty, of which Asahel was the chief. There are thirty-one mentioned in the list, including Asahel; and these added to the two superior orders make thirty-seven. Two of them, we know, were already dead; namely, Asahel [2Sa 3:30] and Uriah [2Sa 11:17]; and if the dead, at the drawing up of the list, amounted to seven, then we might suppose a legion of honor, consisting of the definite number thirty, where the vacancies, when they occurred, were replaced by fresh appointments.

Jamieson Fausset-Brown

I would present 3 possibilities:

Some, like Uriah, are known to have perished in combat. (2 Samuel 11:24) Despite having been murdered during David's reign, Uriah is mentioned. It's therefore plausible that there were more than thirty members on the squad at one point, but that number may have been reduced to thirty due to deaths or departures. Perhaps the list was compiled retrospectively to include and honor those who had served.

This also means that some spots could have been filled and therefore totaled 37, but was at the time only 30.

They were only called "the Thirty" as an approximate figure rather than to be exact.



The full list of the mighty men of David is located in 2 Samuel 23 and
includes the following names:

Josheb-basshebeth, a Tahchemonite
Eleazar, the son of Dodo
Shammah, the son of Agee the Hararite
Abishai
Benaiah
Asahel
Elhanan
Shammah of Harod
Elika of Harod
Helez the Paltite
Ira, the son of Ikkesh of Tekoa
Abiezer of Anthoth
Mebunnai the Hushathite
Zalmon the Ahohite
Maharai of Netophah
Heleb, the son of Baanah of Netophah
Ittai, the son of Ribai of Gibeah of the people of Benjamin
Benaiah of Pirathon
Hiddai of the brooks of Gaash
Abi-albon the Arbathite
Azmaveth of Bahurim
Eliahba the Shaalbonite
The sons of Jashen
Jonathan
Shammah the Hararite
Ahiam, the son of Sharar the Hararite
Eliphelet, the son of Ahasbai of Maacha
Eliam, the son of Ahithophel of Gilo
Hezro of Carmel
Paarai the Arbite
Igal, the son of Nathan of Zobah
Bani the Gadite
Zelek the Ammonite
Naharai of Beeroth
Ira the Ithrite
Gareb the Ithrite
Uriah the Hittite





Reference:




https://www.preceptaustin.org/2-samuel-23-commentary



